# Is there a way to declare in a web page that all javascript http requests must be only to same host?

Tags: javascript, security

I have a small site that shows ads from different ad networks. Sometimes these ad networks serve ads that contain js code that makes HTTP requests to external servers and I found that sometimes those requests violate the privacy of my users.

Is there a way to block js request to other servers? (even if I lose the potential income from that ad or get banned from the ad network)

Comment: Honestly that sounds like a problem that's better-solved in a non-technical way: pick an ad-network that doesn't allow this kind of request. Granted, ensuring they don't happen (accidentally or through malice) even *when* using such an ad network might be worth it. I don't know if there's an easy way to do it though.

Comment: @apsillers Your answer seems to describe exactly what I need. Can you repost your comment as an answer so I can accept it?
P.S. I don't care if I get blacklisted. The problem is that Ad Networks "cheat" on their own privacy policy and my users are complaining loudly about the ads...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A page can use a [Content Security Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP) (CSP), either via HTTP header on the network response or via `<meta>` tag within the page. CSPs are used to control what external origins a page can communicate with.

A CSP can have many different *directives* which control different kinds of external requests. You sound particularly interested in the [`connect-src`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/connect-src) directive, which limits what origins scripts can reach via `fetch` (and similar APIs).

Note that scripts can still initiate external requests by adding external resources to the page, e.g., `<img>`, `<object>`, `<link>`, etc. If you want to limit all external requests, you can use `default-src 'self'` to have all directives default to only the same origin as the page itself. You can then add additional specific directives that are more permissive, if needed.

For instance, this policy blocks all foreign-origin requests and resources, except allowing frames, images, and scripts from `ads.example.com` (and the original origin, too):

```
default-src 'self'; img-src 'self' https://ads.example.com; script-src 'self' https://ads.example.com; frame-src 'self' https://ads.example.com
```

Since `connect-src` is not specified, it is limited by `default-src` and will not allow script communication to foreign origins.